# Asserting height has changed using Capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have an iframe which is the target of a form:

```
<form target="preview">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>

<iframe name="preview"></iframe>
```

The form is submitted when the user types in the textarea (I've left out the debouncing code for brevity):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  // debouncer ensures this happens at *most* every two seconds
  $('form').submit();
});
```

And I have a script which keeps the iframe's height adjusted to its content:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
  var height = $('body', $(this).contents()).height();
  $(this).height(height);
});
```

Now I'm writing a feature spec to assert that the height adjustment actually occurs. I've established that I need to use `evaluate_script` to get the height of the iframe. So, theoretically, my spec should look something like:

```
def preview_iframe_height
  page.evaluate_script('$("iframe").height()')
end

scenario 'preview grows to content', js: true do
  initial_height = preview_iframe_height
  fill_in('Content', with: 'some content')
  expect(preview_iframe_height).to be > initial_height
end
```

However, this code doesn't wait for the request to repopulate the iframe and always fails. I know Capybara is well adept at waiting for content to appear using matchers like `have_content` but I'm not sure how to go about waiting for the height to change. Any ideas?

My test suite:

- RSpec
- Capybara
- Poltergeist

Comment: You may find this link helpful: 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara it's about waiting for ajax to finish, but you could adapt it to waiting until your jquery finishes resizing, then checking the height after that,

Comment: You might find this helpful too: http://animalssittingoncapybaras.tumblr.com/ It will take your mind off the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @taryn-east's comment above, I've successfully adapted [this from Thoughtbot's blog](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara):

```
def preview_iframe_height
  page.evaluate_script('$("iframe").height()')
end

scenario 'preview grows to content', js: true do
  page.execute_script(%{
    iframe_loaded = false;
    $('iframe').load(function() {
      iframe_loaded = true;
    });
  });

  initial_height = preview_iframe_height
  content = "line\n\n" * 30
  fill_in('Content', with: content)

  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
    loop until page.evaluate_script('iframe_loaded')
  end

  expect(preview_iframe_height).to be > initial_height
end
```

This defines a variable, `iframe_loaded`, and sets it to `true` when the iframe has finished loading. The spec waits for `iframe_loaded` to become `true` before continuing with its expectation.

This can be abstracted into a helper method for more general use.

Please upvote @taryn-east's very useful comment on the question as well!